# Convergence of probability densities

Tags: statistics, integration, convergence-divergence

I appreciate if you can give me some guidance on how to approach this question:

Suppose $f_n(x) \text{ and } g(x)$ are densities such that for all x, $f_n(x) \rightarrow g(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I need to show two things:

1) $\int |f_n(x) - g(x)|dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

2) if $X_n$ has density  $f_n(x)$ and X has density g(x), and if $\int |f_n(x) - g(x)|dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then:

$$sup_A |P(X_n \in A) - P(X \in A)|\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), do you have any other assumption on $f_n$ (eg, bounded)? If so, you can use the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).
For (2), observe that for any Borel set $A$,

$$
\left|\mathbb P\{X_n\in A\} - \mathbb P\{X\in A\}\right| = \left|\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_A(f_n-g)\right| \leq
\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_A|f_n-g|
$$

Comment: Hi @Clement C. ,
Thanks for your answer. We actually don't have any explicit assumption that $f_n$ is bounded but since they are densities,I guess it implies that they are bounded.

Comment: To apply the DCT, you'd actually need an upper bound of the form $\forall n,\ |f_n|\leq h$ for some function $h$.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a way to circumvent this issue, by decomposing $f_n-g$ into the non-negative and negative parts — see for instance (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_de_Scheff%C3%A9#.C3.89nonc.C3.A9_et_d.C3.A9monstration)*. The result is actually known as Scheffé's Lemma.


* (in French, but the proof itself is $\simeq$ language-independent)

Comment: Cool...Thanks :)